# Lots of empty whitespace in textplot_wordcloud / comparison.cloud

Tags: r, shiny, word-cloud, quanteda

I have a shiny app that plots a wordcloud of terms and trying to get it to fit with labels inside the app is difficult. If I expand the screen everything fits but if I don't labels get cut off and it's because of all that extra whitespace that is forcing the labels so far away. Is there a way to remove the whitespace around the cloud? I read somewhere that's its because of the driver chosen for plot (png vs jpeg etc).
 The code I use for the ui is:

```
 fluidRow(plotOutput('wordcloud', width = "100%", height = '800'))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The **wordcloud2** package works better with Shiny, but does not have a comparison plot. I'm not completely sure how to control the spacing in the `wordcloud::comparison.cloud()` -- all that `quanteda::textplot_wordcloud(x, comparison = TRUE)` does is to pass the arguments through to that function.

Comment: Good to know. Might not be a way around it right now. I'll keep my eyes peeled and report back if I find anything. Thanks Ken!